# Gradient of matrix operations

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product, hadamard-product

Assume we have a matrix $M\in \mathbb R^{t\times qt}$, a vector $p \in \mathbb R^{r}$, and a vector $z \in \mathbb R^{qt}$, .

Note that $\otimes$ is a Kronecker product and $\odot$ is a Hadamard product (Schur product), $\mathbf 1_i$ is a $i$-dimensional all-one vector, and $I_i$ is a $i\times i$ identity matrix.

How to calculate the gradient of the following expression with respect to $z$?

$$
\left( I_{t}\otimes \mathbf 1_{r}^T \right) \left( I_{tr} \odot \left( \left(Mz\otimes \mathbf1_{r} - \mathbf 1_{t}\otimes p\right)\mathbf1_{tr}^T \right) \right) \left(Mz\otimes \mathbf1_{r} - \mathbf 1_{t\times 1}\otimes p \right) 
$$

Comment: You can use this [matrix calculator](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the following properties of the Diag operation
$$\eqalign{
A &= {\rm Diag}(a) = I\odot a{\tt1}^T = I\odot {\tt1}a^T \\
B &= {\rm Diag}(b) \\
Ab &= a\odot b = b\odot a = Ba \\
}$$
and of the Kronecker product of two vectors
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(aI_1b^T) &= {\rm vec}(I_aab^T) &= {\rm vec}(ab^TI_b) \\
b\otimes a &= (b\otimes I_a)a &= (I_b\otimes a)b \\
}$$
For typing convenience, define the following variables
$$\eqalign{
Q &= (I_{m}\otimes{\tt1}_n) \\
x &= (Mz\otimes{\tt1}_n -  {\tt1}_m\otimes p) 
  \;&\in {\mathbb R}^{mn\times 1} \\
X &= {\rm Diag}(x) \\
}$$
Using the above, rewrite the function and calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
y &= Q^T(I_{mn}\odot x{\tt1}_{mn}^T)x
  \;\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times 1} \\
  &= Q^TXx\\
dy &= Q^T\,dX\,x + Q^TX\,dx \\
   &= 2Q^TX\,dx \\
   &= 2Q^TX\,(M\,dz\otimes{\tt1}_n) \\
   &= 2Q^TX\,(I_m\otimes{\tt1}_n)M\,dz \\
   &= 2Q^TXQM\,dz \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} &= 2Q^TXQM \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! May I ask why $Q^TdX x = Q^T X dx$?

Comment: The first part of the answer explains how diagonal matrices behave with vectors, i.e. $Ab=Ba.\,$ Since $(X,\,dX)$ are diagonal matrices and $(x,\,dx)$ are the corresponding vectors, the result follows.